# Add comments with a file

Tags: discussion

I'm really gratefully with the post
[How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I would like to make a contribution, but not sure how to attach a file into a post, I wrote to simples scripts in order to get oracle installed into our Ubuntu.

How do I do it?

Comment: Since this is about the site itself, you should ask on [meta]. However, this site doesn't have any way of "attaching" files. Maybe publish your scripts on Github and provide the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot muru,

I'll follow your suggest.

Answer (score 4):

If your scripts are your answer to the question "How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04?", then you can post them as an answer right there. Just write a short explanation of what the scripts do and how they work, and post them as an answer to the question.